# Get Twitter userid from access token only

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

This may be duplicated with other articles, but I can't figure out how to do it after reading all of those.

I'm working on a back-end project in PHP and we are isolated from the front-end. According to the documentation from the front-end team, they will pass an access token and need the back-end to pull `userid` from Twitter's server.

Is there any way to do it? I could pull the data if I have `oauth_signature` and `oauth_nonce`, but they only give us the access_token.

Answer (score 0):

> I could pull the data if I have `oauth_signature` and oauth_nonce

That's not correct. `oauth_signature` is generated based on the application secret and request parameters. `oauth_nonce` is just a random string

So you need to get `access_token` **and** `access_token_secret` and perform a [`GET account/verify_credentials`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/account/verify_credentials) request

Further reading:

- https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849